# Why isn't my useState() hook setting a new state inside useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to detect if a `<section>` element is focused in viewport, I'm unable console.log **a single** `true` statement. I'm implementing a `[isFocused, setIsFocused]` hook for this.

This is my window:

[image]

I needed so when `Section 2` is positioned at the top of the window, a single `console.log(true)` shows up. But this happens:

[image]

This is my implementation:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const SectionII = (props) => {
  const sectionRef = useRef();
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const section = sectionRef.current;
    const { y } = section.getBoundingClientRect(); 

    if(!isFocused && y <= 0) {
      setIsFocused(true);
      console.log(isFocused, y);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <section id="mentorship" ref={sectionRef} style={{borderTop: "1px solid"}}>
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <button>Set hash</button>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SectionII;
```

Why wouldn't my state by updated to `true` with `setIsFocused(true)` inside `if(!isFocused && y <= 0)`?

Thanks so much for the insight. I'm really stuck.

Comment: You can't console log the new state immediately after updating it. `isFocused` is a `const` meaning it **cannot** change during the current function call. Instead it will be set to the new value on the *next* function call (next render). You can check it's value by moving your console log to the component body.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using any state management in react, you need to ensure that the change is set before attempting to access the new state value. For your example, you immediately `console.log(isFocused, y)` following your setState function (changes will only appear on the next DOM render). Rather, you should use a callback with the set state function, `setIsFocused(true, () => console.log(isFocused, y))`.

Comment: The useState setter does not have a callback parameter.